# Using plugins with cordova/ionic framework

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to use [this plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications) so that I can send local notifications on ios, however, whenever i try to install it with their instructions (`cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications.git && cordova prepare`), when I load it up on the emulator and try to test it, it doesn't work. When I do:
`alert(window.plugin)`
I get an `undefined`. I should get something like `[object Object]`. This makes me think that the plugin is somehow not installed correctly or something. Uninstalling and reinstalling does not work. Is there another step somewhere to get in order to use the plugin?

Comment: Whatz showing when this command is executed `cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications.git`

Comment: Is the alert(window.plugin) executing before Cordova is ready? You have to run that only after Cordova is ready.

Comment: @dino the code is executing after cordova is ready.

Comment: @JeremyWilken cordova is ready when i execute the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

window.plugin will only exist when running on a device.
It does not work in simulated environments.

Also, to make your life easier, I would suggest checking out http://ngcordova.com, which takes care of installation and interfacing within ionic for a whole bunch of useful plugins, including local and push notifications.

Comment: I thought it was supposed to work on simulators. I will try on a real device